# Cast exception during serialisation of a tree structure to JSON

Tags: c#, json, tree, json.net

I have been working on a little project and have stumbled into an issue.  I have been using the object type implemented [here](http://www.siepman.nl/blog/post/2013/07/30/tree-node-nodes-descendants-ancestors.aspx) during the project and wished to be able to convert it to a JSON string through the Newtonsoft Json.NET [library](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and then save it to a text file.  I have previously tested the class with custom structures and the like and found no issues with it so far, however when I attempted to serialise the object the exception below was shown:

> Unable to cast object of type 'AuriEngineTest.Node`1[System.String]' to type 'System.String'.'

A minimal example of the code leading up to this point can be found below:

```
Node<string> scene;    
scene = new Node<string>("Root");
var textToSave = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scene);
string fileLocation = "C://..."
File.WriteAllText(fileLocation, textToSave);
```

I wish to clarify if the custom class used to create the Node structure is for some reason not supported, and if that is the case is there an alternative method to serialise the object, be it to JSON or a viable alternative.

Kind regards, 
Shadow

Comment: Are you sure this exception occurs when trying to serialize, and not when you are deserializing the object from JSON?

Comment: Yes I am.  I specifically separated the serialisation step from the deserialisation step as I am saving rather than loading the file.  There is no deserialisation occuring before it which is exactly what confused me.

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem even further. On what line is the exception occurring? And have you tried using the explicit type parameter for the `SerializeObject` function (even though it should be resolved)? Eg. `JsonConvert.SerializeObject<Node<string>>(scene)`.

Comment: I did attempt that at first but it returned an error before compiling, stating that the SerializeObject method cannot be used with type arguments.  And the exception is happening on the SerializeObjects line.  I will try and check further give me a sec.

Comment: The exception was thrown at the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteValue step.  Beyond that I am not sure as the line numbers are purely related to the serialisation step, which would be expected as I have now removed any other uses of the library from the code to fully isolate it.  So yes it is just the SerializeObject line which threw the exception and the JsonWriter which appears at the top of the stacktrace for it.

Comment: My apologies. The type parameter obviously won't work with the `SerializeObject` function. I had it confused with the deserialization function.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the idea to try it anyhow!

Comment: could you relevant json here?

Comment: If I had been able to serialise the Node<string> object then I could, however I haven't been able to produce the JSON string, which is my issue currently.

Comment: can you show me your class "Node" ?

Comment: The class node is identical to the linked page (first link in question ) but I will try and upload it when I am back at my computer.